# phpunit: Error class not found

Tags: php, phpunit

I've read other questions related to this problem. But it seems the suggested answers couldn't solve my problem.

My project directory structure:

```
app/models/User.php
tests/UserTest.php
vendor/
composer.json
composer.lock
phpunit.xml
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.5"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-4":{
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

**phpunit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         verbose="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="User Test">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

**User.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

class User{
    public $firstname;
    public function setFirstName($firstname){
      $this->firstname = $firstname;
    }
}
```

**UserTest.php**

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\Models\User;

class UserTest extends TestCase{
    public function testTrue(){
        $user = new User();
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

I am executing this sample test but I keep getting:

```
Error: Class 'App\Models\User' not found
```

How to properly test User class in this particular setup?

Comment: It is psr-4. The Namespace must match the folder-structure AND the case of the folders. Try renaming the folder `models` into `Models`.

Comment: same problem. Class not found.

Comment: Did you try `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: yes.. composer dump-autoload -o

Comment: Did you try to add the file-suffix to the directory-tag in your phpunit.xml? So that it reads `<directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>`.